# Decrypt unicode text from DB

Tags: java

i have a problem when i try to save encrypted "password-text" to SQL server 2008r2 Database. When i save from java-Netbeans, sql receives "?????" on text field, i found that is because or unicode... i'm using BLOWFISH Encryption (The class works perfect) but i can't decrypt it because i'm getting from DB "????" text instead of original text(password)

Do you know how can i fix this issue?, a friend told to use "varbinary" on DB instead of "varchar", but no idea how to do :S

Thanks

```
public boolean SavetoDB() {
    DATABASE_CONNECTION con = new DATABASE_CONNECTION();
    cn = con.conectar();

    boolean resp = false;
    try {
        String sql = "INSERT INTO cliente(usuario, pass, Nombre, Apellido, Edad,"
                + "genero, Direccion, Telefono, Celular, img_name,tipo_cuenta, ipaddress, puerto,segundos,minutos,horas)"
                + " VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,?,?,?,?,?)";
        PreparedStatement cmd = cn.prepareStatement(sql);
        cmd.setString(1, usuario);
        cmd.setString(2, pass);
        cmd.setString(3, Nombre);
        cmd.setString(4, Apellido);
        cmd.setInt(5, Edad);
        cmd.setString(6, genero);
        cmd.setString(7, Direccion);
        cmd.setInt(8, Telefono);
        cmd.setInt(9, Celular);
        cmd.setString(10, nombrearch);
        cmd.setString(11, tipo_cuenta);
        cmd.setString(12, ip);
        cmd.setString(13, puerto);
        cmd.setInt(14, 1);
        cmd.setInt(15, 0);
        cmd.setInt(16, 0);
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////


        if (!cmd.execute()) {
            resp = true;
        }
        cmd.close();
        cn.close();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("Error: " + ex.getMessage());
    }
    return resp;
}
```

SQL TABLE:

create table cliente(

usuario varchar(15) not null primary key,

pass varchar(90) not null,

Nombre varchar(32) not null,

Apellido varchar(32) not null,

Edad int not null,

genero varchar(15) not null,

Direccion varchar(32),

Telefono int,

Celular int,

img_name  varchar(32) not null,

tipo_cuenta varchar(15) not null,

fecha_creacion date,

ipaddress varchar(20) not null,

puerto varchar (30) not null,

segundos int not null,

minutos int  not  null,

horas int not null,

)

Comment: Show some code that shows your saving and receiving process.

Answer (score 1):

Try saving a md5/sha digest of the password text bytes in the database. When you need to check the password, calculate the digest of the entered password and compare with the one in the database.